# How can I exit the entire script if

Tags: bash

How to stop a script if it has been run using bash test.sh or ./test.sh?

```
# if the script was run with bash test.sh or ./test.sh, stop

echo "From here the script only works if it has been run with source test.sh or . test.sh"
```

Comment: See [How to define a shell script to be sourced not run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424492/how-to-define-a-shell-script-to-be-sourced-not-run)

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score -2):

ctrl+c if it was not send in background. if it is in background then
run
 ps aux | grep test.sh
then grab the process id from the PID column
then use the kill to stop it. so if the PID is 3946 for example. run
kill 3946
then run again 
ps aux | grep test.sh
and if the only result you get is your grep then the process has stopped. Else you might need to force it with the 
kill -9 3946
that a bit more brutal but use as last resort.
you can run
kill -l
that will give you the list of signal you can send to the process with the kill command
cheers

Comment: This is not understandable. Please clarify.